# JavaScript - Declaring Global Scope for Nested Function?

Tags: javascript, function, scope

My attempts at giving global scope to a nested JavaScript function are not working:

```
//DECLARE FUNCTION B IN GLOBAL SCOPE
function B;

function A() {

    //DEFINE FUNCTION B INSIDE NEST
    B() {
        alert("function B is running");
    }
}

//CALL FUNCTION B FROM GLOBAL SCOPE
B();
```

This is just curiosity -- you are correct that I don't really have any good reason to want to do this.

TIA -- I don't have an SO account to respond to your answers...

Comment: I don't think you need an account to comment on answers to your question.

Comment: You can always register. Won't hurt. :) As you can see there are lots of very prominent users on Stackoverflow (ie. Jon Skeet, Joel Spolsky, Jeff Atwood...)

Answer (score 16):

`function B;` will simply generate a syntax error.

You can use a [*function expression*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope#The_function_expression_(function_operator)). As functions are first class objects, you can assign a function to a variable:

```
var B; // declare (global) variable (outer scope)

function A() {
    // assign a function to it
    B = function() {
        alert("function B is running");
    };
}

// we have to call A otherwise it won't work anyway
A();
// call B
B();
```

You could also let `A` return a function:

```
function A() {
    return function() {
        alert("function B is running");
    };
}

B = A();
```

This would make the relation between `A` and `B` a bit clearer.

Of course you can always define a global variable by omitting `var`, but you should use this very carefully. Use as less global variables as possible.

```
function A() {
    B = function() {
        alert("function B is running");
    };
}
```

And I bet there is a better way of doing it, depending on what your actual goal is.

---

[More about Functions and function scope.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope)

Answer (score 4):

What about:

```
function A() {
    window.B = function() {
        alert("function B is running");
    }
}
//CALL FUNCTION B FROM GLOBAL SCOPE
B();
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do something like this:

```
function outer() {
  function inner() {
    // ..
  }

  window['inner'] = inner;
}
```

It's a little icky to have a direct reference to "window", so you could do this (from the global context):

```
(function (global) {
  function inner() {
    // code code code ...
  }

  global['inner'] = inner;
})(this);
```

Answer (score 0):

There appear to be a couple of issues with your code

1. The first line doesn't appear to be legal Javascript (JSLint agrees).  To declare an uninitialized variable use the `var B;` syntax
2. The code never calls A to initialize B so calling B() is invoking an uninitialized variable
3. I'm fairly certain the code to initialize B inside of A is also not legal.

Try the following

```
var B; // Establish B as a global scope variable

function A() {
  B = function() {
    alert('B is running');
  };
}

A(); // Call the function which will cause B to be initialized
B(); // Run B
```

Answer (score 0):

You're close, but not completely correct.

1. You have to define B as a variable and then assign a function to it.
2. Also run A() before executing B, otherwise B will be undefined. The easiest way of running it is the way that I show in my code example.

These are the **smallest amount of changes** to your code to make it work as you asked:

```
var B;

(function A() {
    // define function B
    B = function() {
        alert("function B is running");
    }
})();

// call function B globally
B();
```